# ruby default argument idiom

Tags: ruby, default, default-value, idioms

What's the idiom in Ruby when you want to have a default argument to a function, but one that is dependent on another parameter / another variable? For example, in Python, an example is:

```
def insort_right(a, x, lo=0, hi=None):
    if hi is None:
        hi = len(a)
    while lo < hi:
        mid = (lo+hi)//2
        if x < a[mid]: hi = mid
        else: lo = mid+1
    a.insert(lo, x)
```

Here, if `hi` is not supplied, it should be `len(a)`. You can't do `len(a)` in the default argument list, so you assign it a sentinel value, None, and check for that. What would the equivalent be in Ruby?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
def foo(a, l = a.size)
end
```

Comment: what happens if you have a loop? `def foo(a=b, b=a)`. or can you only refer to vars defined before?