# Ruby use case for nil, equivalent to Python None or JavaScript undefined

Tags: javascript, python, ruby, null

How does Ruby's `nil` manifest in code? For example, in Python you might use None for a default argument when it refers to another argument, but in Ruby you can refer to other arguments in the arg list (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3875943/ruby-default-argument-idiom)). In JS, `undefined` pops up even more because you can't specify default arguments at all. Can you give an example of how `RubyNone` pops up and how it's dealt with?

I'm not looking for just an example using `nil`. Preferably it would be a real code snippet which had to use `nil` for some reason or other.

Comment: @delnan: that's the one. i'm looking more for use case than the variable name in Ruby, so i've edited the question to reflect that

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Ruby's [nil](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/NilClass.html) and Python's `None` are equivalent in the sense that they represent the absence of a value. However, people coming from Python may find some behavior surprising. First, Ruby returns `nil` in situations Python raises an exception:

Accessing arrays and hashes:

```
[1, 2, 3][999] # nil. But [].fetch(0) raises an IndexError
{"a" => 1, "b" => 2}["nonexistent"] # nil. But {}.fetch("nonexistent") raises an IndexError
```

Instance instance variables:

```
class MyClass
  def hello
    @thisdoesnotexist
  end
end

MyClass.new.hello #=> nil
```

The second remarkable fact is that `nil` is an object with lots of methods. You can even convert it to an integer, float or string:

```
nil.to_i # 0
nil.to_f # 0.0 # But Integer(nil) or Float(nil) raise a TypeError.
nil.to_s # ""
```

Comment: what does the `@` mean in the instance variable example?

Comment: Instance variable names start with `@`, class variables with `@@`.

Comment: @x is equivalent to self.x in Python (though the OOP patterns in Ruby and Python are very different).

Comment: If you do `[1, 2, 3].fetch(999)` instead, you'll get an exception. If you have warnings on, you'll get a warning about `MyClass.new.hello`. If you do `Integer(nil)` or `Float(nil)`, you'll get `TypeError`s. `String(nil)` gives you an empty string, though. Also, do you mean "permissive" (allowing a lot of things), not "promiscuous" (having sex or interactions with many things)?

Comment: @Andrew: I'll incorporate your notes to the answer, thanks. I thought  "promiscous" could be used metaphorically... I'll change it.

Comment: @tokland: It can be used metaphorically: [Promiscuous_(disambiguation)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Promiscuous_(disambiguation)) , which is why I put "or interactions" in my comment.

Answer (score 2):

One use of `nil` you often see in Ruby code is the following:

```
a ||= 10 # or a = a || 10
```

This works because once a variable has been seen on the left hand side of an assignment, it implicitly has the value nil.

```
>> if false 
..   x = y
..   z
..   end
=> nil
>> x
=> nil
>> z
NameError: undefined local variable or method `z' for main:Object
```

Thus when the `a || 10` part is evaluated, it evaluates to `nil || 10`, which yields 10.

`nil` and `false` are also the only two values in Ruby that are logically false, so it's customary for methods to return `nil` in case of failure. There's a gem called `andand` that makes use of exactly this, so instead of something like

```
@first_name &&= @first_name.trim
```

you can write

```
@first_name.andand.trim
```

This basically translates to trim `@first_name` if it has a value other than `nil`, otherwise evaluate to `nil`. As you can imagine this is particularly useful when chaining methods where one of the intermediaries can potentially return `nil`.

Besides that `nil` is also returned when you are trying to access non-existing collection elements, e.g. in the case of arrays or hashes. Uninitialized instance variables also have the value `nil`.

I'm not overly versed in Python, but from what I've seen `nil` and `None` serve pretty much the same purpose.

Comment: now that "andand" pops up, I have to recommend the ick project (same author) and it's "maybe" pattern, really nice! this_may_be_nil_or_a_string.maybe.strip # string stripped or nil

Comment: `andand` and `maybe` remind me of the `Maybe` monad in Haskell.

Comment: @Claudiu: Not to be confused with the `mebbe` keyword in lolcode.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to all explanations about nil, ruby also has 'defined?'.

```
a = nil

p defined?(a)  #=> "local-variable"
p a.nil?       #=> true
p defined?(b)  #=> nil
```

Answer (score 0):

My Ruby-fu is very weak, but `nil` might be what you are looking for. Here is a quick illustration of using `nil` in a function as default argument.

```
irb(main):003:0> def foo(a = nil)
irb(main):004:1> puts a
irb(main):005:1> end
=> nil
irb(main):006:0> foo(1)
1
=> nil
irb(main):007:0> foo()
nil
=> nil
irb(main):008:0>
```

Comment: Don't get confused by the `=> nil` in the output up there: that's irb showing the the return value of the `foo` method.

Answer (score 0):

They’re also used in place of `void`: In a static language the compiler will simply forbid you from using the return value of a `void` function, but in a dynamic language every procedure has to return *something*. So the special value `nil` is used.

Comment: it's possible to have a dynamic language which would just throw an exception if you try to use the result of a function that didn't return anything. i just dont think any do it.